# WPF How to bind XML with multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I have this dataset I'm consuming from a web service. It looks like XML generated from Microsoft ADO. I'd like to bind this data to a WPF datagrid in C# but I can't quite figure out how to code the namespaces.

```xml
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<rs:data>
    <z:row ResumeID='7217937' FullName='Brianna Burgwell' AddressLine1='430 Bar Ranch Rd.' AddressLine2='' City='Buford' PostalCode='90210' State='CA' Country='US'/>
    <z:row ResumeID='7218085' FullName='Mandy Philips' AddressLine1='200 Beltway Loop' AddressLine2='' City='Buford' PostalCode='90210' State='CA' Country='US'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

If I strip out all of the namespace prefixes and make it simple XML, this XAML works:

```cs
<Grid.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="applicants" Source="sample.xml" />
</Grid.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="applicantGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource applicants}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/data/row}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="12,12,31,12" SelectionChanged="applicantGrid_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ResumeID" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ResumeID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@FullName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But with the namespaces, I can't figure out the right configuration of XmlNamespaceMappingCollection.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a collection of namespaces in the `XmlNamespaceMappingCollection` and apply to your `XmlDataProvider` using the `XmlNamespaceManager` property

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection x:Key="myNamespaces">
       <XmlNamespaceMapping Uri="http://www.somenamespace.com" Prefix="namespace1"/>
       <XmlNamespaceMapping Uri="http://www.anothernamespace.com" Prefix="namespace2"/>
    </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="applicants" XmlNamespaceManager="{StaticResource myNamespaces}" Source="sample.xml" />
</Grid.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="applicantGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource applicants}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/data/row}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="12,12,31,12" SelectionChanged="applicantGrid_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ResumeID" Binding="{Binding XPath=namespace1:ResumeID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=namespace2:FullName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```